# on my console app the relative path doesn't work, but why?

Tags: c#, file, path, trace

I am learning to learn C#. I was studying the usage of TraceSwitch and the Microsoft configuration extension using vs code and a console app, but for some reason, the relative path doesn't work.

Project Structure
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX34L.png)

Here is the code:

```
...
// The error is here
const string APP_SETTINGS = @"appsettings.json";

if (File.Exists(APP_SETTINGS))
{
    ....
    //rest of the code
    ....
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("File doesn't exist");
}
```

The only way that worked was by using the complete path:

```
const string APP_SETTINGS = @"C:\Users\myUser\source\repos\cs11dotnet7\Chapter04-vscode\Instrumenting\appsettings.json";
```

But why? The book I am using was using the relative path. I tried the relative path using:

./
/
.
\

But nothing worked.

Comment: When you access a file via a relative path (like `"appsettings.json"` (as.j)), the access is relative to the _current working directory_ (CWD). Your program can change the CWD while it's running, but by default,  it's where the program starts (likely in .\ bin\debug, relative to your source folder). I'm guessing that your as.j file is located in your source folder. Does it get copied to your exe's folder? If not, force it to be by looking at the file's properties and setting "copy always"

Comment: You could capture the current directory into a variable to view to diagnose this sport of thing.  always check your assumptions first.  Also note that many things can change the CWD like using a File/Folder browsing dialog

Comment: Put a temporary call to `Path.GetFullPath` in your code, and then compare what you see in the debugger to what you expect (and where you see the file). Remember, your running program has no clue where your source files are located

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the program was running from the path ".bin\debug\net7.0". To solve this issue, I made the following changes:

I added the following code to the .csproj file to update the properties of the program:

```
    <ItemGroup>
       <None Update="appsettings.json">
         <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
       </None>  
   </ItemGroup>
```

This code ensures that the "appsettings.json" file is copied to the output directory of the application.

By doing this, the file is now copied to the working directory of the app, which resolved the problem.

Another solution I found was to manually move the "json" file to the appropriate directory.

Thank you for the help!